# Show div if dates from two inputs with jQuery datepicker do not match

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have 2 inputs which have jQuery UI Datepickers attached to them. Basically a to and from date.

I want to be able to show a div when the 2 dates do not match from the 2 inputs.

I tried playing around with the following code below which shows an alert when 2 inputs match using jQuery .blur

Problem is after some research .blur doesn't respond too well with the datepicker as when you leave the outside of the input to click a date it triggers.

I suppose I need to find a way around this or if anyone knows any other way of seeing if datepicker inputs values are different.

```
$('input.date').blur(function() {
  if ($('#id1').attr('value') == $('#id2').attr('value')) {
    alert('Same Value'); return false; 
  } else { 
    return true; 
  }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Use the datepicker `onSelect` method to act when the user has selected a date.

Comment: Have you tried `if ($('#id1').val() == $('#id2').val())`? Can you also post a complete code example?

Comment: `.attr()` doesn't get the current value, it gets the original value from the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `change` event of the inputs, like in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/85pNg/)

```
$("input.date").on("change", function () {
    if ($("#id1").val() === $("#id2").val()) alert("DATES ARE EQUAL! :)");
    else alert("DATES ARE NOT EQUAL! :(");
}).datepicker();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onSelect: function(date)
{
  if(date == $('#input2').val() && $('#input2').val() != '' )
{
alert('equal dates');
}
}
```

Use this code in first input